# How can i call Java Script Function form my objective C class

Tags: iphone

I am displaying a URL in uiwebview, and I'm getting a list in popover controller, now my requirement is when user will select any item from that popover list then I need to call a JavaScript function with parameters which I selected and according to my selection JavaScript function will change URL content.

The code which is I am trying to call JS function is given below but it is not working for me:

```
[self.myWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"loadpano(\"panoXML.php?params=panoId=9572|lang=de|parkourId=342\",null,MERGE,BLEND(1));"];
```

Please provide me any solution for that.

Comment: Your call seems right. The problem seems to be specific of krpano. You should test it in Safari desktop (you need to change the user agent to Safari Mobile) to get feedback on any javascript error.